# Using DataSource attribute with .runsettings file

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild, runsettings

I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 and have upgraded my .testsettings file to a .runsettings file. My goal is to use the runsettings file with a TFS build to update certain parameters as needed for a build, but would like to access test parameters located within my test cases by using the DataSource. The error I am facing is the same as described here - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/884cff6a-1da1-44d8-b8c8-d52d6ff12df6/mstest-unable-to-run-the-test-using-runsettings-file?forum=vsunittest.

Using the .testsettings file previously solved the issue, but a runsettings file does not appear to be usable if the testsettings file is being used.

**Update**

Goal - Run a test locally with a runsettings file and using the DataSource attribute to pull parameters from a TFS test case.

Here is the following error when attempting to run a test locally.
[image]

Here is an example test case.
[image]

Here is where the runsettings file is set.
[image]

**Update 2**

I have added the following tag to the runsettings file.

[image]

I have reduced the NuGet 'MSTest.TestAdapter' from 1.1.18 to 1.1.11 and now I am receiving the following error. The exact test will run and connect to the datasource with no issues on Visual Studio 2015 using a testsettings file.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if the .runsettings file getting copied to the build artifact/output?

Comment: Also in the Visual Studio Test build step, did you provide the location of the Run Settings File?

Comment: Could you share more detailed error log info?

Answer (score 0):

First please run your test with MSTest on your build machine manually to check whether it can work or not.

If it can work on build machine, afraid that this problem related to the TFS build definition. Double check some configurations as *alltej* suggested.

If it also failed on build machine, the problem should be caused by the environment. Double confirm your local environment is as the same as  the build machine. It's also able to use .runsetting file of a unit test to connect to the data source. Please follow the tutorial [Configure unit tests by using a .runsettings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file).

Comment: Currently I am only running this on my local machine. I have not moved this to a build definition (I do not want to waste time/effort updating the build definition if this won't be successful locally).

Comment: If so, the issue is more related to local VS. Not related to TFS so far. If you got any problem such as build configurations when you moved on TFS,  my pleasure to give some help or direction.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Is there another MSFT expert that can assist with this issue?

Comment: @Brian will invite someone familiar with vstest when back to office on Monday.

Comment: Any update on inviting someone more familiar with this topic?

Comment: @Brian, In the runsettings file, please make use you’ve specified the correct TestAdaptersPaths at test run configuration part.  And the DeploymentEnable should be set true at MSTest Run Settings part.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I have made those changes and still receive the error.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Also, if I add the tag 'ForcedLegacyMode' under the 'MSTest' tag I get the follow warning and no tests are ran 'A testsettings file or a runsettings with a ForcedLegacyMode set to true is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter.'.